# Jdbi transaction - multiple methods - Resources should be closed

Tags: sonarqube, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

Suppose I want to run two sql queries in a transaction I have code like the below:

```
jdbi.useHandle(handle -> handle.useTransaction(h -> {
                    var id = handle.createUpdate("some query")
                            .executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys()
                            .mapTo(Long.class).findOne().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No id"));

                    handle.createUpdate("INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (id) " +
                                    "VALUES (:id , xxx);")
                            .bind("id")
                            .execute();
            
                }
        ));
```

Now as the complexity grows I want to extract each update in into it's own method:

```
jdbi.useHandle(handle -> handle.useTransaction(h -> {
                    var id = someQuery1(h);
                    someQuery2(id, h);
                }
        ));
```

...with `someQuery1` looking like:

```
private Long someQuery1(Handle handle) {

        return  handle.createUpdate("some query")
                .executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys()
                .mapTo(Long.class).findOne().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No id"));
    }
```

Now when I refactor to the latter I get a SonarQube blocker bug on the `someQuery1 handle.createUpdate` stating:

> Resources should be closed

> Connections, streams, files, and other
> classes that implement the Closeable interface or its super-interface,
> AutoCloseable, needs to be closed after use....*

I was under the impression, that because I'm using `jdbi.useHandle` (and passing the *same* handle to the called methods) that a callback would be used and immediately release the handle upon return. As per the [jdbi docs](https://jdbi.org/#_handle):

> Both withHandle and useHandle open a temporary handle, call your
> callback, and immediately release the handle when your callback
> returns.

Any help / suggestions appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube doesn't know any specifics regarding `JDBI` implementation and just triggers by `AutoCloseable`/`Closable` not being closed. Just suppress sonar issue and/or file a feature-request to SonarQube team to improve this behavior.

Comment: Evaluating JDBI here. I disagree this is good behavior. The object returned from `createUpdate` shouldn't be `Closeable` if it doesn't need to be closed by the caller. Surpressing a resource leak warning should be exceptional, not default for every JDBI interaction. This hit me after 15 minutes of playing with JDBI and I think it will be a deal breaker. A better way would be that `createUpdate` defers creating a prepared statement until `one` or `execute` is called.  There is no need for the object that provides the fluent binding API to be `Closeable`.